# Replacing a fragmented numeric sequence with continuous sequence in data.table

Tags: r

I have a question concerning R and changing values of a numeric sequence. I do have a column in a data.table which looks something like X here:

```
X <- data.table(id = c("103", "103", "103", "104", "104", "160", "160"), 
content = c("I", "don't", "know", "some", "more", "words", "."))
```

And I would like to replace the id values with sequential values to change the starting point and to get rid of the gaps in between. In the real life problem, there would be thousands of id values, so grep-ing them wouldn't be a possibility.

So what I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
Y <- data.table(id = c("0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "2", "2"), 
content = c("I", "don't", "know", "some", "more", "words", "."))
```

Any hint would be welcome as I don't know how to start. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Related: [How to get ranks with no gaps when there are ties among values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915704/how-to-get-ranks-with-no-gaps-when-there-are-ties-among-values). `X[ , id := frank(as.numeric(id), ties.method = "dense") - 1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert 'id' to `factor` and then coerce it to `integer`

```
X[, id :=  as.character(as.integer(factor(id)) - 1)]
```

---

Or use `match`

```
X[, id := as.character(match(id, unique(id)) - 1)]
```

---

Or another option is `.GRP`

```
X[, id :=  as.character(.GRP -1) , id]

identical(X, Y)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
X %>%
   mutate(id = as.character(match(id, unique(id)) - 1))
```

Or

```
X %>% 
  mutate(id = as.character(group_indices(., id) - 1))
```

Or

```
X %>% 
   mutate(id = as.character(cumsum(id != lag(id, default = first(id)))))
```

---

or with `base R`

```
X$id <- as.character(match(df$id, unique(df$id) - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the different approaches. I ended up using the very first solution using factors as this is the one I was thinking of at first, so it's closest to my initial understanding. But it is very interesting to see all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
X[, id := rleid(id) - 1L][]
#   id content
#1:  0       I
#2:  0   don't
#3:  0    know
#4:  1    some
#5:  1    more
#6:  2   words
#7:  2       .
```

If you want `id` to be of type character then do

```
X[, id := as.character(rleid(id) - 1L)]
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very elegant!