# Dense ranking of column based on order of second column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am beating my brains out on something that is probably straight forward. I want to get a "dense" ranking (as defined for the  [`data.table::frank`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.8/topics/frank) function), on a column in a data frame, but not based on the columns proper order, the order should be given by another column (`val` in my example)

I managed to get the dense ranking with [@Prasad Chalasani 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916087/7941188), like that:

```r
library(dplyr)
foo_df <- data.frame(id = c(4,1,1,3,3), val = letters[1:5])

foo_df %>% arrange(val) %>% mutate(id_fac = as.integer(factor(id)))
#>   id val id_fac
#> 1  4   a      3
#> 2  1   b      1
#> 3  1   c      1
#> 4  3   d      2
#> 5  3   e      2
```

But I would like the factor levels to be ordered based on `val`. Desired output:

```r
foo_desired <-  foo_df %>% arrange(val) %>% mutate(id_fac = as.integer(factor(id, levels = c(4,1,3))))
foo_desired
#>   id val id_fac
#> 1  4   a      1
#> 2  1   b      2
#> 3  1   c      2
#> 4  3   d      3
#> 5  3   e      3
```

- I tried `data.table::frank`
- I tried both methods by @Prasad Chalasani.
- I tried setting the order of `id` using `id[rank(val)]` (and `sort(val)`, and `order(val)`).
- Finally, I also tried to sort the levels using `rank(val)` etc, but this throws an error (`Evaluation error: factor level [3] is duplicated.`)
- I know that one can specify the level order, I used this for creation of the desired output. This solution is however not great as my data has way more rows and levels

I need that for convenience, in order to produce a table with a specific order, not for computations.

<sup>Created on 2018-12-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you even need `factors` ? Not sure if I am missing something but this gives your desired output.

You can use `match` to get `id_fac` based on the occurrence of `id`s.

```
library(dplyr)

foo_df %>%
    mutate(id_fac = match(id, unique(id)))

#  id val id_fac
#1  4   a      1
#2  1   b      2
#3  1   c      2
#4  3   d      3
#5  3   e      3
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I don't need factors - it was only my method to get this dense ranking. Very nice solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can check with `first`

```
foo_df %>% arrange(val) %>% 
          group_by(id)%>%mutate(id_fac = first(val))%>%
          ungroup()%>%
          mutate(id_fac=as.integer(factor(id_fac)))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     id    val id_fac
  <dbl> <fctr>  <int>
1     4      a      1
2     1      b      2
3     1      c      2
4     3      d      3
5     3      e      3
```

Comment: That's a nice approach. However, I will accept @Ronak Shah's answer as more direct.