# How to get relative rankings of numeric elements in a list or vector in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, rank

**Quick note regarding similar questions:** This question was initially flagged as similar to [How to emulate SQLs rank functions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446254/how-to-emulate-sqls-rank-functions-in-r), and [How to get ranks with no gaps when there are ties among values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915704/how-to-get-ranks-with-no-gaps-when-there-are-ties-among-values). However, the first reference assumes the user understands the SQL rank function, which I and probably many other users don't know SQL or its rank function, and the second reference addresses ranking tied elements whereas my question addresses both ties and large gaps (>1) between the elements. I believe my question title is broader and better verbalizes the issue for users. Thus I petition to leave this question stand.

**The original question re: relative rankings of elements:** I've been playing around with `rank()`, `order()`, `seq()`, `list()`, and `unlist()` functions in R in order to get the relative ranking of each element in a list in R. In the two examples illustrated below, I'm trying to derive the yellow columns showing the relative rank of each element. How can this be done? I have a preference for dplyr if it's easier to execute than in base R.

[image]

When I run the following code for the illustrated Example 1, I get these results which is not what I want:

```
> rank(Example1$Element)
[1] 3 3 3 6 3 7 3

Example1 <- data.frame(Element = c(1,1,1,2,1,3,1))
rank(Example1$Element)
```

Comment: Note that it's debatable whether in ex1 2 and 3 are the 2nd and 3rd highest. In sports when there's a tie in 1st place, the next athlete or team is ranked in 3rd place, not the silver medal. `rank(Example1$Element, ties.method = "min")` accounts for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `dplyr::dense_rank()`:

```r
# Example 1
dplyr::dense_rank(c(1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1))
#> [1] 1 1 1 2 1 3 1

# Example 2
dplyr::dense_rank(c(4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1))
#> [1] 3 1 1 1 2 4 1

# Example in code
dplyr::dense_rank(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1))
#> [1] 1 1 1 2 1 3 1
```

Comment: Some `dbplyr` backends also translate `dense_rank()` to SQL queries when working with database connections, making it slightly more widely applicable than a base R solution.

Answer (score 2):

In base R, a trick is to use `as.numeric` with `as.factor`:

```r
as.numeric(as.factor(Example1$Element))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 1 3 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `match`, i.e.

```
match(Example1$Element, sort(unique(Example1$Element)))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 1 3 1
```

Comment: Note that you need a `sort()` around the `unique()` to get the correct result if the unique levels don't already appear in sorted order in the data.